# Nginx Cache and Yii

Tags: caching, yii, nginx

I have a configure for my Nginx+php-fpm
I made nginx caching
in http section

```
fastcgi_cache_path /var/cache/nginx/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=nginx_webpy_cache:1m inactive=1d;
fastcgi_temp_path    /var/cache/nginx/temp;
```

in server section

```
set $no_cache 0;
    if ($request_method = POST)
    {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }
    #Don't cache if the URL contains a query string
    if ($query_string != "")
    {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }
    #Don't cache the following URLs
    if ($request_uri ~* "/(api/|login|logout|corporate/login|corporate/logout)")
    {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }
    #Don't cache if there is a cookie called PHPSESSID
    if ($http_cookie = "PHPSESSID")
    {
        set $no_cache 1;
    }
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
        fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /srv/www/site/index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        fastcgi_cache nginx_webpy_cache;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 304 2m;
        fastcgi_cache_key "$request_method|$http_if_modified_since|$http_if_none_match|$host|$request_uri|$cookie_login_id";
        fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
        fastcgi_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
    }

location ~* \.(ico|js|txt|jpg|jpeg|png|css|pdf)$ {
        root /srv/www/site;
        access_log off;
        expires 1h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
```

Mostly working ok, but i can't logout, i logout and still like login user, how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in most cases you can't really cache any pages under authentication with the server HTTP caching. Users will be simply seeing someone else's pages, for example, while trying to access their own profiles (unless your URLs are really distinctive, which is normally not the best practice either).

The solution would be to use fragment caching, see [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.fragment) for Yii-specific tutorial.